# Make interactive console active by default in pycharm while debugging

Tags: python, debugging, console, pycharm

I've been using interactive console while debugging in PyCharm. But with each rerun of debugger I have to press button for console over and over again. I wonder is it possible to make it active by default without need of pressing the button?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if this was really a problem, but it resolved when I installed professional edition of PyCharm.